# Sort order of transactions on blockchain.info

Tags: transactions, blockchain

This list of transactions is supposed to be sorted by time, newest first: https://blockchain.info/address/1BWk7rcf4fRS6XHEDqVQPeeoZitGB65GYE?sort=1

However the transactions are not displayed in chronological order.  Is this a bug? Is it ordered by something else?

Also what is the transaction time?  Is it the time a transaction is submitted to a node or is it the time a transaction is added to a block?

Comment: Blockchain.info probably uses their own time vs time specified in transaction. Transaction time stamps are medians.